# Recover data from Memory Stick Pro Duo

Tags: data-recovery, memorystick

I need to recover my data from my Memory Stick Pro Duo. It is not detectable by anything, not my PC, not my PSP, nor camera, nothing. But i need the data. It is very important. I have tried all recovery software but none of them function as it is not detectable. I dont even have enough budget to sent to a recovery lab. Is there any way I can do this.

Please....................

Appreciation in Advance

Comment: Are you using the same card reader?

Comment: I tried to read it through three different things, my PSP, camera, card reader

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the contacts on the memory card are clean and not damaged.

Comment: I am not sure what you exactly mean by `Contacts on the Memory Card` can you explain a bit

Comment: At one end of the memory card (the one with the cutout on the corner) you should see some electrical contacts, Gold in colour. They'll be slightly recessed. If there is any dirt or grease on these contacts, then they will not make a good contact with your card reader. Use something like isopropyl alcohol and a SOFT toothbrush, always brushing towards the edge of the card. If you can't get access to the alcohol, get a piece of stiff paper, fold it once and then use the crease to firmly but gently rub the contacts. Don't go hard enough to tear or damage the paper.

Comment: I tried it, didn't work.